# Getting error while implementing monaco editor with react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am implementing monaco editor in react typescript with webpack 5 and I am new in webpack getting an error "jsonp chunk loading:27 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 4902 failed."

I have to implement monaco editor and see the xml proper formatting code and coloring .

It should like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXvk6.png)

```js
webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const ESLintWebpackPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const lifecycle = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const mode = lifecycle === 'start' ? 'production' : 'production';
const devtool = 'inline-source-map';//lifecycle === 'build' ? false : 'eval';


module.exports = {
  mode,
  entry: {
    main: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './index.tsx'),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'target/webpack'),
    globalObject: 'self',
  },
  plugins: [
    new ESLintWebpackPlugin({
      failOnWarning: false,
      failOnError: true,
      extensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
      files: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/lib'),
      ],
      exclude: [
        'node_modules/',
      ],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'index.css',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  devtool,
  cache: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/lib'),
      ],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: { presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'] },
    }, {
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/lib'),
      ],
      exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/lib/thirdparty'), /node_modules/],
      loader: 'ts-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            additionalData: '@import "./index.scss";',
          },
        },
      ],
    }, {
      test: /\.svg/,
      type: 'asset/inline',
    }, {
      test: /\.ttf(\?.*$|$)/,
      type: 'asset/resource',
      generator: {
        filename: './[name][ext]',
      },
    }, {
      test: /\.json/,
      type: 'json',
    }],
  },
  devServer: {
   
    devMiddleware: {
      index: true,
      publicPath: '/ui',
    },
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    liveReload: false,
    client: {
      overlay: false,
    },
    static: [{
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './src/main/webapp'),
      publicPath: '/nwc-ui',
    }, {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './src/main/resources/ui'),
      publicPath: '/',
    }, {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './src/main/resources'),
      publicPath: '/',
    }],
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{
        from: /^\/ui\/configuration$/, to: '/module.json',
      }],
    },
  },
};
```

```css
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import '../../../../../../res/css/editor/style.css';
// import { EditorService } from './editorService';
import { setDiagnosticsOptions } from 'monaco-yaml';

import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';

interface IMonaco { 
  languages: { 
    json: { 
      jsonDefaults: { 
        setDiagnosticsOptions: (arg0: { 
          validate: boolean; schemas: 
          { uri: string; fileMatch: string[]; schema: 
          { type: string; properties: { 
            p1:{ enum: string[]; }; 
            p2: { $ref: string; }; }; }; 
          }[]; }) => void; }; }; }; 
}

const ReactEditor = (): JSX.Element => {
  const getYAML = () => {
    window.MonacoEnvironment = {
      getWorker(label) {
        switch (label) {
          case 'editorWorkerService':
            //new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker', import.meta.url));
            return new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker', import.meta.url));
          case 'yaml':
            return new Worker(new URL('monaco-yaml/yaml.worker', import.meta.url));
          case 'workerMain.js':
            return new Worker(new URL('monaco-yaml/yaml.worker', import.meta.url));
          default:
            throw new Error(`Unknown label ${label}`);
        }
      },
    };
  };

  const editorWillMount = (monaco:IMonaco) => {
    getYAML();
    setDiagnosticsOptions({
      validate: true,
      schemas: [{
        uri: 'http://myserver/foo-schema.json',
        fileMatch: ['*'],
        schema: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            p1: {
              enum: [ 'v1', 'v2'],
            },
            p2: {
              $ref: 'http://myserver/bar-schema.json',
            },
          },
        },
      }],
    });
  };

  const originalCode = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="value for the deployed Web.config file" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>`;
  const options = {
    selectOnLineNumbers: true,
    automaticLayout: true,
    contextmenu: false,
    minimap: { enabled: true },
    readOnly: true,
    language: 'xml',
  };
  const renderEditor = ()=>{
    return (<MonacoEditor
        width='800'
        height='600'
        language='xml'
        theme="vs"
        value={originalCode}
        options={options}
        editorWillMount={editorWillMount}
      />);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderEditor()}
    </div>
  );
};
export default observer(ReactEditor);
```